# How do configure grails to preserve your grails.app.context variable when generating a war?

Tags: java, grails, war, grails-2.0

With grails you change the rootContext of the application when running it using grails run-app by using the grails.app.context variable. However, when generating a war grails allows the servlet container to set the context by leaving the configuration out of web.xml. Is there any way to preserve the config in web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way. As said earlier, `grails.app.context` is used for run-app where we know the embedded servlet container is either Tomcat or Jetty.

In case of a `war`, the application will not know which container will the war be deployed. It is upto the container to set the context root which vary from one to another.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully this becomes available starting grails 3.0!